# how to get the firebase UID of the user who logged in via google?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get UID of user who signed in via google.

When I'm using `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` its obviously shows error.

When I'm using `GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getContext()).getId` its show incorrect ID .

How could I get this his UID?

There is code that I used to sign in via google. I get it from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

```
signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("R.string.default_client_id")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);

    signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent sign = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(sign, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_CODE);
        }
    });

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_CODE){
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            System.out.println("firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle( account.getIdToken());
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
        }
    }
}
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,NavActivity.class));
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

This is how I get the UID

```
String uid = "";
    if(firebaseUser!=null ){
        uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
    }
```

Comment: "its obviously shows error." What error do you get?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

Comment: That means that no user is signed into Firebase when you make that call. From the information you shared it is impossible to say why that is. I recommend posting enough minimal context for us to reproduce the problem. For this and more guidance on how to maximize the chances someone can help, check [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added code now

Comment: How is the `firebaseUser.getUid();` related to the code that sets `firebaseUser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your google sign-in token to log into Firebase.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleSignInAccount.getIdToken(), null))
```

Because your FirebaseUser and your Google account are using two different authorizations, therefore can't be used interchangeably.

Comment: I've already done this, but it's the same error anyway

Comment: `public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        >>>> FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,NavActivity.class));
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                }`
can you print the uid of this user? this should be the uid you seek

Answer (score 1):

If there's no user logged in, the `.getCurrentUser()` method will return null.
Make sure you have this logic in your app to prevent the crash:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
    Log.d("TAG", user.getUid())
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```

The method to get UID remains same irrespective of which authentication method you use. As long as a user is logged in, there's an UID.

Answer (score 1):

With Flutter, after login action with google.

```
String? uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his comment, the NPE raises because of the fact that **no** user is signed in. To be able to use the UID that comes from the authentication process, you should always check for nullity. In Kotlin, it will simply be:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.apply {
    Log.d("TAG", it)
}
```